# How to stop overwriting and carryone under in textfile from python?

Tags: python

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

These are a few variables

```
 name=input("whats your name?")
    device=input("whats device do you have?")
    phone=input("whats your phone number?")
    prob=input("whats your problem?")


    with open("scr.txt", mode='w') as file:
        file.write(str("Date and Time: "))
        file.write(str(now))
        file.write(str("\nName: "))

    file.write(str(name))
    file.write(str("\nPhone Number: "))
    file.write(str(phone))
    file.write(str("\nProblem: "))
    file.write(str(prob))
    file.write(str("\nDevice: "))
    file.write(str(device))
    file.write(str("\nCase Number: "))
    from random import randint
    file.write(str(randint(1000000,9999999)))
```

This overwrites the text file whereas I need it to write under the previous text every time used.

Comment: Then don't use (over)`w`rite mode when opening the file, use `a`ppend.

Comment: You want to **append** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in append (a) mode:

```
with open("scr.txt", mode='a') as file:
    # Here ----------------^
```